# How to move a portable texlive installation

Tags: texlive, texlive-2017

I just moved a portable texlive installation from one computer to another. After that, my documents wouldn't compile anymore, with a more or less cryptic error message:

```
) (c:/path/to/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from c:/path/to/texlive/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric da
ta not found or bad.
<to be read again>
relax
l.54 \normalsize
```

Red flags came up at `cache`. I deleted the directory `luatex-cache`, restarted the build process and everything worked again. This was easy, but, did I forget anything? How does one actually move a portable installation?

Comment: This feels like a minior thing, but I still wanted to post this here, for others to find, if they run into the same problem.

Comment: The luaotfload-names-database contains absolute pathes to fonts. So if you move your tex-system you should rebuild it.